# Insert data using Entity Framework model

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to insert some data in my database using Entity Framework model, but for some unknown reasons to me, it does nothing.

Am I missing something here?

```
using (var context = new DatabaseEntities())
{
    var t = new test
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
        name = "blah",
    };
    context.AddTotest(t);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Try 'SaveChanges(System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);'

Comment: Code First? Model First? Does it break or does it just not store anything? What does SQL Profiler say? Is there anything being sent to the database at all?

Comment: This `AddTotest(t)` method is a custom method. Since it's not shown what happens there, this question can't be answered.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

It should be:

```
context.TableName.Add(TableEntityInstance);
```

For versions of entity framework before 6, it was:

```
context.TableName.AddObject(TableEntityInstance);
```

Where:

1. `TableName`: the name of the table in the database.
2. `TableEntityInstance`: an instance of the table entity class.

If your table is `Orders`, then:

```
Order order = new Order();
context.Orders.Add(order);
```

For example:

```
 var id = Guid.NewGuid();
    
 // insert
 using (var db = new EfContext("name=EfSample"))
 {
    var customers = db.Set<Customer>();
    customers.Add( new Customer { CustomerId = id, Name = "John Doe" } );
  
    db.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Here is an example:

```
public void UpdatePlayerScreen(byte[] imageBytes, string installationKey)
{
  var player = (from p in this.ObjectContext.Players where p.InstallationKey == installationKey select p).FirstOrDefault();

  var current = (from d in this.ObjectContext.Screenshots where d.PlayerID == player.ID select d).FirstOrDefault();

  if (current != null)
  {
    current.Screen = imageBytes;
    current.Refreshed = DateTime.Now;

    this.ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
  }
  else
  {
    Screenshot screenshot = new Screenshot();

    screenshot.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    screenshot.Interval = 1000;
    screenshot.IsTurnedOn = true;
    screenshot.PlayerID = player.ID;
    screenshot.Refreshed = DateTime.Now;
    screenshot.Screen = imageBytes;

    this.ObjectContext.Screenshots.Add(screenshot);
    this.ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have any AddObject method.

Comment: @Dennis Traub asked you about your Model. Please provide more info about it.

Comment: It doesn't break. It's not storing anything. I have no problem in listing the content of my table. Sorry, I'm new to this, I'm not using SQL Profiler. My model just has one table with 2 columns.

Comment: Put more code.  I have to see which a Model your application is using.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I have no idea what more do you want to see. All the code my app currently has, is the one I pasted here, plus the namespaces.

Comment: Use .Add rather than .AddObject

Comment: On EF 6, you would use .Add rather than .AddObject

Comment: Same for me, in EF6 you have to use .Add then only there's no error. But still u did a great job explaining the concept, i understand them now ;)

Comment: Fantastic answer! thanks for this as it shows how to read and write using the entity framework

Answer (score 47):

```
var context = new DatabaseEntities();

var t = new test //Make sure you have a table called test in DB
{
    ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
    name = "blah",
};

context.test.Add(t);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Should do it

Answer (score 11):

[HttpPost] // it use when you write logic on button click event

```
public ActionResult DemoInsert(EmployeeModel emp)
{
    Employee emptbl = new Employee();    // make object of table
    emptbl.EmpName = emp.EmpName;
    emptbl.EmpAddress = emp.EmpAddress;  // add if any field you want insert
    dbc.Employees.Add(emptbl);           // pass the table object 
    dbc.SaveChanges();

    return View();
}
```

Comment: if any query ask me