# Entity Framework not showing inserted data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a strange problem (or I am not seeing something obvious :) )

First, I am getting data from dbcontext:

```
            using (var dbContext = new DemoDataDBContext())
            {

                var data = (from m in dbContext.Customer
                            where m.datecreated >= DateFrom
                            && m.datecreated <= DateTo
                            orderby m.datecreated ascending
                            select m).Take(PageSize).ToList();

                Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(data);
            }
```

Data is displayed, everything ok.
Next, I am inserting new record (different procedure):

```
                Customer tmp = new Customer()
                {
                    name = CurrentCustomerName,
                    address = CurrentCustomerAddress,
                    datecreated = DateTime.Now
                };

                dbcnt.Customer.Add(tmp);
                dbcnt.SaveChanges();
```

Here is the problem. When using first procedure again, I am getting the same data as first time (without new inserted object).

Any ideas why am I not getting new data?

One more thing - when restarting app new data is visible.

Comment: You can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835434/insert-data-using-entity-framework-model

I hope this work for your project.

Comment: Did you look for a copy of your database file in bin/debug folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is getting inserted in your database. It could be the where conditions and page size that are limiting the data from being shown on screen.

Try removing those conditions to debug and you will be able to find the problem

Comment: Correct, time component of datetime was a problem!

Damn energy drinks and no sleep! Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help. I prefer coffee :)