# update database through textbox

Tags: c#, linq

I need a simple linq query by which i can update the database .here we have a text box and file upload and a submit button .after clicking on submit button it uploaded the file but didn't insert the textbox value to db may be there is the problem in linq query.so i need a simple linq query for that.

```
 public DateTime validdate(string validfromdate)
        {
            using (var db = appDataContextFactory.GetNewDataContext())
            {
                DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(validfromdate,"dd / MM / yyyy", null);
                var lstdate = db.ExchangeRates.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ValidFromDate ==DateTime.Now);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return (dt);
            }
        }
```

please review the above code.

Comment: @PranavPatel which part is missing or will you share sample code for these..

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8835510/5001784

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var db = appDataContextFactory.GetNewDataContext())
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(validfromdate,"dd / MM / yyyy", null);
            var lstdate = db.ExchangeRates.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ValidFromDate ==DateTime.Now);
            var yourItem = new ExchangeRate();
            yourItem.ValidFromDate = yourDate;
            db.ExchangeRates.Add(yourItem);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return (dt);
        }
```