# can I do insert without all the fields in the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

This is probably a very basic question but I havn't done many web app development; my very first serious app development.

So, now the app contains over 40 labels that I would like to update into a database.
But, I do not know if what I am doing is in the right direction cos I am using one table to do update or insert depending on the situations.
But, I just want to test out if I can just update a few columns instead of the full table .  Can it be done ?
I do not want to create a separate table, just use the one that has 40 columns.

Comment: Currently how are you trying to update? Are you using ADO.NET or EF?

Comment: We need to know your database schema and how you are doing the update and insert.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, say if you have a Table with 3 columns you can insert values for just the first 2 columns or any combination **if the fields accept null values or have default values:**

```
Table
Column1   int
Column2   int
Column3   int   Null Values [ticked]  or default value = 0
```

SQL:

```
INSERT INTO Table
(Column1, Column2) 
VALUES
(1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is certainly possible.

You have multiple options now-a-days to interact with your database from an ASP.Net application.

You can either do it using a simple SQL 'INSERT' query as mentioned by Jeremy Thompson and use the **command** property in case you are using ADO.Net.

Here's an example of the [command](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c5c6e2/working-with-command-object/) object.

```
INSERT INTO Table
(Column1, Column2) 
VALUES
(1,2)
```

Or the other option is to use an ORM such as Entity Framework.

In case you are using Entity framework; you can then work with dbContext class (Database context), update your table using an object and call SaveChanges method of dbContext to persist the changes to database.

Here's a related question that might provide you more detailed information on how to insert data using [Entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835434/insert-data-using-entity-framework-model).

Can you provide more information on what all components/frameworks are you using as part of your web application? It will then be easier to guide you more appropriately.

Comment: Hi raring, I am trying to use Asp.net webform C#, Json combined with Stored Procedure without entity framework or any other ORM as part of the requirements.

Comment: ok, that makes it even simple as now you can simply write an insert query as specified in the afore-mentioned example and call a stored procedure using ADO.Net SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery method. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi raring, tks. But, now I am facing problem with this insert cos this form is not so straight forward as some of the fields are autopopulated with data.  Anyway, I will post to Stackoverflow as a separate question.  Appreciate your reply.