# How to read data from text file and store in database table using C#?

Tags: c#, database, file, text, separator

```
#Softdrinks
Cola 2
Sprote 3
Fant 4
Redbull 2
#Pide-Lahmacun
Pide Mozarella 12
Pide Hackfleisch 12
Pide Feta-Hackfleisch 14
Pide Spinat 13
Pide Spinat-Ei 14
```

above is the text file format. here # define the category name of product.'Cola 2' define the product name and the price. Where product name is Cola and price is 2. now how to add this data into my product table.I am using c# and SQL. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Tried this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/585ca635-1f7d-4be7-85ed-cded7d18eaef/how-to-convert-a-text-file-into-database-using-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code to parse text file and then use string to put into database.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ConsoleApplication108
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);

            string line = "";
            string category = "";
            string pattern = @"(?'name'.*)\s+(?'price'\d+)";
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith("#"))
                    {
                        category = line.Substring(1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Match match = Regex.Match(line, pattern);
                        string name = match.Groups["name"].Value.Trim();
                        string price = match.Groups["price"].Value.Trim();

                        Console.WriteLine("category : '{0}', name : '{1}', price : '{2}'", category, name, price);

                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to write to the database. Just create your SQL connection. I would suggest using entity framework. Have a look at this link for entity framework.
[Insert data using Entity Framework model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835434/insert-data-using-entity-framework-model)

```
    public int InsertItem(string item1, string item2, string item3)
    {
        using (var connection = CreateDBConnection())
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = @"
                INSERT dbo.TableName(item1, item2, item3)
                OUTPUT Inserted.Id
                VALUES (@item1, @item2, @item3)";

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@item1", item1));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@item2", item2));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@item3", item3));

            connection.Open();
            return (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try something like this:**

1. Split by newlines
2. Find the matching lines by the regex
3. Select the capturing group 1 and 2
4. Map the groups to an anonymous type
5. Make an empty DataTable
6. Populate the DataTable now.

**[The regex: (.*?)\s(\d+)](https://regex101.com/r/fgxOjq/1)**

**Explanation of the Regex:**

```
1st Capturing Group (.*?)
.*? matches any character (except for line terminators)
*? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

\s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

2nd Capturing Group (\d+)
\d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

---

**The code:**

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(@"test.txt");

string pattern = @"(.*?)\s(\d+)";

var query = contents.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, pattern))
                .Select(x => Regex.Match(x, pattern))
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Name = x.Groups[1].Value,
                    Value = Convert.ToInt32(x.Groups[2].Value)
                });

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", Type.GetType("System.String")));
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));

foreach (var item in query)
{
    DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();
    dr["Name"] = item.Name;
    dr["job1"] = item.Value;
    dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```