# id entering as 0 in database in MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

So I'm having some issues with my code here as I am new to C# and linq.
I'm trying to insert id, icon_url and count values into my database. But when I'm inserting the first row, the id is set as 0 and when I add another row, I'm getting two errors. I want to auto increment the ID as it is primary key and is of type int. How can I fix this? 
Please see codes and screenshots below.

**IMAGES**

DATABASE
[image]

DATABASE DESIGN
[image]

ERROR 1
[image]

ERROR 2
[image]

**CODE:**

```
bool imcount = db.dashboards.Any(dash => dash.icon_url.Contains(imageurl));
  if (imcount == false)
  {
    using (ECardModel db = new ECardModel())
    {


      dashboard imageCount = new dashboard()
      {

        icon_url = imageurl,
        count = 1
      };

      db.dashboards.Add(imageCount);
      db.SaveChanges();
    }
  }
  else if (imcount == true)
  {
    using (ECardModel db = new ECardModel())
    {
      int icount = db.dashboards.Where(dash => dash.icon_url.Contains(imageurl)).Max(dash => dash.count);

      dashboard imageCount = new dashboard()
      {
        count = icount + 1
      };
      db.dashboards.Add(imageCount);
      db.SaveChanges();
    }
  }
```

**Update:**

When I set identity specification to "Yes", it is giving me another error.
Please note that i am unable to update my .edmx model as it is in xml format and not showing model diagrams. Also, the number 0 is still inserted in the database.
Please see image below.
[image]

Comment: share your table schema, seems like you just made your column as primary key and not setting any value in above code.

Comment: SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON(in database table) for Id column and refresh your model.

Comment: @DarkRob Yes you are right, but I do not know how to add and auto increment the values of id.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10992074/11276273

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update any column to auto increment from front end using query.

You have 3 options:

Option 1:-
Either update it using SQL mangement studio.

[image]

Option 2:-
Drop your column and create new one. If there is no record in your current table.
But this will change the ordinal position of your column.

```
-- ID is the name of the  [to be] identity column
ALTER TABLE [yourTable] DROP COLUMN ID 
ALTER TABLE [yourTable] ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Option 3:

You may drop your current table and create it again with the column set as `IDENTITY`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT [PK_table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: I tried your solution but getting another error. Please see update above. Thank you for your help.

Comment: seems like you are inserting value in `id` column, which is not required as it is auto generated. No need to set id for new inserted row.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the thing is I do not know where this value is being inserted as I have just been given this project to handle. Is there any way I can track it down?

Comment: please find this link for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835434/insert-data-using-entity-framework-model.