# How to fix "This database cannot be imported. It is either an unsupported SQL Server version or an unsupported database compatibility."

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i make a service based database  , every time i try to insert data , it seems the application works fine , but when i reload the database and want to see the data it show this messages `"This database cannot be imported. It is either an unsupported SQL Server version or an unsupported database compatibility."` and the data not updated, i dont know how to fix this , already search some solution from SO but still not get it ..

if you need some details , you can ask in comment *because i dont know what to put in this

EDIT :
App.conf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Database1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="Database1Entities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="TravelokaCMR.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

how i insert data

```
Database1Entities1 db = new Database1Entities1();
 foreach (string files in filesindirectory)
            {
                string name = Path.GetFileName(files);
                string subname = name.Substring(10, 8);
                DateTime subTime = DateTime.ParseExact(subname, "yyyyMMdd", null);
                TimeSpan span = otime2.Subtract(subTime);

                if (span.Days < 2)
                {
                    // Console.WriteLine(files);
                    foreach (string subfiles in Directory.GetFiles(files))
                    {
                        xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(subfiles);
                        xlWs = xlWb.Sheets[1];
                        xlRange = xlWs.UsedRange;
                        rowFile = xlRange.Rows.Count;
                        colFile = xlRange.Columns.Count;

                        dataFile = new string[rowFile][];

                        for (int i = 0; i < dataFile.Length; i++)
                        {
                            dataFile[i] = new string[colFile];
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < rowFile; i++)
                        {

                                try
                                {
                                    dataFile[i][0] = xlWs.Cells[i + 1,  1].value2.ToString();
                                    //MessageBox.Show(dataMapping[i][j]);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ee)
                                {
                                    dataFile[i][0] = "";
                                }

                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < rowFile; i++)
                        {
                            CMRTable cmr = new CMRTable();
                            items = dataFile[i][0].Split(';');

                            cmr.Merchant_name = items[1];
                            cmr.Sett_date = items[2];
                            cmr.Proc_date = items[3];
                            cmr.Mid = items[4];
                            cmr.cardtype = items[5];
                            cmr.Trx_date = items[6];
                            cmr.Jam_trx = items[7];
                            cmr.Auth = items[8];
                            cmr.Cardno = items[9];
                            cmr.Trx_type = items[10];
                            cmr.amount = items[11];
                            cmr.rate = items[12];
                            cmr.disc_amt = items[13];
                            cmr.tenor_ins = items[14];
                            cmr.rate_ins = items[15];
                            cmr.disc_ins = items[16];
                            cmr.net_amt = items[17];
                            cmr.purchase_id = items[18];
                            cmr.merchant_descriptor = items[19];
                            db.AddToCMRTables(cmr);
                            db.SaveChanges();

                        }
```

Comment: Code that shows how you initialize con and how you are reading data

Comment: Also please tell us what database you are using...

Comment: @RonBeyer hmm i create service-based database here

Comment: @RonBeyer and dont have sql server here

Comment: Which line in the code gives the error?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya nothing wrong with the code, its works fine but the database isn't updated with the data that has been inserted to the database , when i try to refresh it shown the error “This database cannot be imported. It is either an unsupported SQL Server version or an unsupported database compatibility.”, and when i refresh , the database is empty , not a single data is there its like the insert failed

Comment: `reload the database and want to see the data` how and where do you do that?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Server explorer -> expand the database,  expand the tables, choose the table , right click and show table data -> refresh

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya reload the database : Server explorer -> right click on database ->refresh / press the icon refresh in the server explroer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert data using Entity Framework model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835434/insert-data-using-entity-framework-model)

Comment: @Jawad no .. already do the addobject and still the same

Comment: i think the problem is in the connection string like many people suggest , but i dont know how to change the connection string

Comment: Have you tried `db.CMRTable(cmr)` instead of `db.AddToCMRTable()`

Comment: @Jawad it won't work , because CMRTables is not a function .. only can do db.cmrtable.add, db.addtocmrtable, db.cmrtable.addobject

Comment: Then you need to use db.cmrtable.add(cmr) and then saveChanges

Comment: @Jawad already sir , still won't work , ..

Comment: @Jawad maybe you can help me intepreted this messages , "There is wrong choice when I select data source. And there is a db copy in a folder that my data connection point to it, not to my db which pointing to desired path based on query "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204856/discussion-between-jawad-and-trytocode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a chat, following was found.

In looking at your connection string, it seems like the path to your mdf is not correct. Please look into replacing the |DataDirectory|\ with actual path and retry the process.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Database1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=**|DataDirectory|**\Database1.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="Database1Entities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=**|DataDirectory|**\Database1.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="TravelokaCMR.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=**|DataDirectory|**\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**NOTE:** Each of your connection string points to Database1.mdf. Not sure if thats intentional.