# I want to save search results to SQL Server database table using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5, I used Entity Framework to create model using Database 
 First. The model contains the Title, Link and Description of the result as the table in databases.

Now, I want to save those `(Title,Link,Description)` into my table in SQL Server Database. Whenever I do a Research I want those researches to be saved automatically into database.

Actually I have no clue about this. So, **Please help me**.

-- This is the model --

```
public partial class Result
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Snippet { get; set; }
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public string Query { get; set; }
        public string Index { get; set; }
    }
```

-- This is the result view page --

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("Index");}
<ul id="resultslist">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li style="width:600px">
            <a href="@item.Link" style="color:blue;font-size:17px">@item.Title</a><br />
            <span style="color:green;font-size: 14px">
                @item.Link<span>
                    <br />
                    <span style="color:grey">@item.Snippet<span>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

-- This is the result view --

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835434/insert-data-using-entity-framework-model

Comment: I will try that even if i haven't understood it. Thank You so much

Comment: Basically you just create an entity assign values into it's properties and load it into database.

Comment: @John Ronald  Could you please explain more

Comment: I need some more info for that. How do you do the Research ? Do you use any controller method for that ? Where do you get those data from ?

Comment: yes there is a controller where the whole code run

Comment: add an image of it