# How do i input text in EF Core through Console.Readline?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I want to be able to enter a name tomy database through Console.Readline();
But I never manage to make it work.
I have tested the following options down below. But I always get an error that there is no object or that it is not possible to convert a string to my model

Any ideas?

**My code**

```
 private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        private readonly Customer _customer;

        public AddCustomer(ApplicationDbContext db, Customer customer)
        {
            _db = db;
            _customer = customer;
        }


        public void AddCustomers()
        {


     var CustomerName = _customer.Name.ToString();
 

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter customer name");
            CustomerName = Console.ReadLine();
            _db.Add(CustomerName);



        }

      
    }
```

**My model**

```
public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string CustomerDog { get; set; }

        public string CustomerDogBreed { get; set; }

        public int CustomerDogSocialNumber { get; set; }

        public Services services { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Surely it's because you're trying to add a string to the db? You've provided a db model there but you arent even adding that. You'd need to create a new `customer` object and then set the name of that object to `customerName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in my comment. You're trying adding `CustomerName` to the db but I seriously doubt any table in the db is a string table.

To add a new customer to the customer table you'd need to create a new `customer` object, set the `Name` to the customer name and add it.

Please see this: [Insert data using Entity Framework model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835434/insert-data-using-entity-framework-model)

Comment: Thank you. Now i get it, i didnt thought of create i new object, i just created a name :)