# Inserting records in EF many-to-many

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 tables as below created using EF

```
User (Id, Name)
Roles (Id, Name)
UserRoles (UserId, RoleId)
```

In my case, rows are already present in `User` and `Roles`. Now I want to build an admin function and an API through which I would like to assign `User` to `Roles`.

Can someone please explain how to insert rows into `UserRoles`? Also would be great if someone can give a json body as well for say adding User (1) to Roles (A,B,C) and say add Role (A) to user (3,4)

I saw some examples where you can insert into `User` or `Role` and then add to `UserRoles`. But I could not find any help in cases where `User` and `Roles` are already present and need to be assigned only.

Comment: As you mention that both Users and Roles records are existed, then you only need to insert the record to UserRoles table by providing the UserId and RoleId.

Comment: yes...basically in sql I wish to do Insert into UserRoles values (1,A)  // (1,B) (1,C) etc. But how to do that using EF?

Comment: Check this out: [Insert data using Entity Framework model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8835434/8017690)

Comment: I used a DTO and its working now.